# change font size in UILabel based on auto layout (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uinavigationbar, ios-autolayout

I've got a UILabel placed inside a UINavigationBar.
I want to increase the font size of that label based on the height of the `navigationBar`. When the `navigationBar` is large, I want the font size to be bigger, and when I scroll and the `navigationBar` shrinks, I want the font size to decrease.

What I've got so far (inside viewDidLoad):

```
dateLabel.text = "16. Oktober"
dateLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
dateLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
dateLabel.backgroundColor = .white
dateLabel.numberOfLines = 1
dateLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(dateLabel)


dateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
dateLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor)!, constant: -16).isActive = true
dateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.trailingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
dateLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
dateLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topAnchor)!, constant: 16).isActive = true
```

I set up constraints so that `dateLabel` shrinks based on the height of the `navigationBar` (which is working, as you can see in the screenshots).
However, the font size of `dateLabel` does not change.

The screenshot shows the different states of the `navigationBar` when I scroll.

[image: navigationBar]

What do I have to do to decrease the font size of the `dateLabel` based on the height of the `navigationBar`? Is this possible with auto layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UILabel` has no methods automatically reducing font to fit content size or height - only width.

So you should do it by manually changing font due to size changes (don't forget to test result sizes with `UILabel` not `NSString.sizeWithFont:`: results would be slightly different).

You can try to set constraints of your container to preserve `UILabel`'s aspect ratio. This way when you reduce height, width will be reduced too and `UILabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` would do it's work. Should be rough, but enough in you case and much easier and faster to implement.

*UPDATE*

Forgot to mention. I spoke about your concrete example. Behaviour depends on `numberOfLines` and `lineBreakMode`. Making the first != 1 and second something like `.byTruncatingTail` (default value) will display close to necessary (but, for example, will wrap words when width isn't enough - while you expect no wrapping at all).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the snippet below.

```
        dateLabel.text = "16. Oktober"
        dateLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 40)
        dateLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        dateLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        dateLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        dateLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        dateLabel.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
        dateLabel.backgroundColor = .orange
        dateLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.container.addSubview(dateLabel)
```

It would give you the desired result. I have added a gif of example did with above snippet in Xcode playground. You can refer that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to achieve by setting 
the below properties in Attribute inspector.

- set Autoshrink to Minimum Font Size
- Provide the minimum font size

Please refer the attached screenshot for reference.
[image: UILabel properties for Autoshrink]

Answer (score 0):

In which method you change the hight of the navigation bar, put this in there:

```
height = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height
dateLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: height / 3)
```

Please note that I just typed it in here, might contain typo

Comment: You can also play with that font size calculation. for example: 2.5*CGFloat.squareRoot(height) might be better.